# in App purchase AlertMessage

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, uialertview

I want to change the alert message in the inApp purchase.
The text coming is :-

DpO you want to buy one  ** **** ***** levels for Rs**?

I want to make it like :- Do you want to buy  ** **** ***** levels for Rs**?

In short i want to remove "One" word from the inApp purchase alert message which is coming from the appstore.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can not change the text, its coming from App Store.

Comment: is there not any way to remove the word ONE ?

Comment: few days back my client also reported same issue. I tried to remove that 'One' word. But finally come to know its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to change the system message that is presented for the In App Purchase.

I added an In App Purchase to one of my apps recently and didn't come across the option/ability to tailor that message.

What's more, looking at some of the apps that I've downloaded that have In App Purchases, they all have the same, default wording.

I assume that Apple have added the word, "one", to make it explicit that the user is buying a quantity of one, of whatever the IAP is. Allowing developers to change this text would open up the possibility for ambiguity in the purchase process, potentially miss-selling, whether deliberate or accidental...

Hope that helps,
Gavin